# Image upload to Azure

Tags: c#, image, azure, webclient

I created a web app in Azure. This was a simple web app created using microsoft asp .net. I downloaded my azure profile and published to the azure web app using visual studio. There is an image folder in the web app. When I published all the images uploaded like a charm. Then I used a WPF smartclient app using a web client object and set its Credentials to network credentials along with the user id and the password of my azure account. But when the line reaches the webclient.upload kind of method, I am getting a 401 unauthorized exception. It looks to me that when I try to upload my credentails are not taken as correct. If it were IIS, I know what to do. But in AZURE I am not sure how I can give an anonymous user and access to upload the image. Any comments or points to be considered here?

Answer (score 0):

If your images are not a static part of your application but instead they can be created from your application (example user uploading his picture) I would recommend using Azure Storage instead of file system (you wont loose images uploaded by your users after you do next deploy).

Azure Storage can be easily managed both from [code](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/) as well as using GUI management tools like [CloudBerry Explorer](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/free-microsoft-azure-explorer.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

1. adding name space

`using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;`

2.Adding class

```
 public class blobservice
    {
        public CloudBlobContainer GetCloudBlobContainer()
        {
            string connString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName="";AccountKey=E"";";
            string destContainer = "mysample";
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connString);
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(destContainer);

            if (blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists())
            {
                blobContainer.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions
                {
                    PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
                });

            }
            return blobContainer;
        }
    }

3..aspx.cs

 blobservice _blobServices = new blobservice();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        blobservice _blobServices = new blobservice();
        Upload();
    }

    public void Upload()
    {
        CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = _blobServices.GetCloudBlobContainer();
        CloudBlockBlob blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("Sampleblob.jpg");
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        byte[] bytes = wc.DownloadData(Server.MapPath("~/Images/active.png"));
        using (Stream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            blob.UploadFromStream(ms);
        }
    }
    protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Name = "https://bikeimages.blob.core.windows.net/mysample/Sampleblob.jpg";
        Uri uri = new Uri(Name);
        string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath);
        blobservice _blobServices = new blobservice();
        CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = _blobServices.GetCloudBlobContainer();
        CloudBlockBlob blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);
        blob.Delete();
    }
```